# Price above / below 4hr ichimoku cloud confluence not working properly

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I use the 15min timeframe (TF) for entries and as a buy / sell confluence I use the price above / below  Ichimoku cloud on the 4hr TF.

I created a table so when I am on the 15min TF, I can see the above condition without having to go back and forth between the 15m and 4hr TF.

Here is the relevant code I am using:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Ichimoku 4h cloud table", shorttitle="Ichimoku 4h cloud table", overlay=true)

conversionPeriods = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Conversion Line Length")
basePeriods = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Base Line Length")
laggingSpan2Periods = input.int(52, minval=1, title="Leading Span B Length")
displacement = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Lagging Span")
donchian(len) => math.avg(ta.lowest(len), ta.highest(len))
conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)
spanA = math.avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
spanB = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)

//Get 4hr values
[conversionLine4h, baseLine4h, laggingSpan2Periods4h] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid , "240", [conversionLine, baseLine, laggingSpan2Periods], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
spanA4h = math.avg(conversionLine4h, baseLine4h)
spanB4h = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods4h)

// calculations for output 4h
longCond4h = close > spanA4h[displacement-1] and close > spanB4h[displacement-1] 
shortCond4h = close < spanA4h[displacement-1] and close < spanB4h[displacement-1] 

status4hcloudbgc = longCond4h ? color.green : shortCond4h ? color.red : color.yellow
```

The above is placed in a table.

I noticed that the above code is not giving accurate results.

Sometimes when I am on the 15min timeframe, the colour of the table changes depending on where the price is in relation to the cloud.

For example if the price on the 4hr TF is above cloud the colour will be green but if I move to the 15min TF where the price on the 15min TF is below the cloud, the table will turn red and not remain green as it is suppoed to.

Can anyone guide me what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the *f_secureSecurity* function from [this library](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/)

Something like that:

```
f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) =>
    request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)


conversionLine4h = f_secureSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, "240", donchian(conversionPeriods))
baseLine4h =  = f_secureSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, "240", donchian(basePeriods))
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav. checked on 4hr timeframe and code which you gave me does not work. Works correctly on 1hr and 15m but works incorrectly on 5m and 1m.
is there something else that might work?